# Recieving File Over TCP Socket in Python

Tags: java, python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send a file over a TCP socket from a Java Client to a Python Server. I have been able to successfully transfer the file, but there is a problem with the server where it fails to recognize the end of the byte stream it is receiving from the client.

Here is my server:

```
import socket

server_addr = '127.0.0.1', 5555

# Create a socket with port and host bindings
def setupServer():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket created")
    try:
        s.bind(server_addr)
    except socket.error as msg:
        print(msg)
    return s


# Establish connection with a client
def setupConnection(s):
    s.listen(5)     # Allows five connections at a time
    print("Waiting for client")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    return conn


def getFile(filename, conn):
    print("Creating file", filename, "to write to")
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        while data:
            print(data)
            f.write(data)
            data = conn.recv(1024)      #This is where the problem is
    print("Finished writing to file")


# Loop that sends & receives data
def dataTransfer(conn, s):
    while True:
        # Recieve a file
        print("Connected with:", s)
        filename = "test.json"
        getFile(filename, conn)
        break

    conn.close()


sock = setupServer()
while True:
    try:
        connection = setupConnection(sock)
        dataTransfer(connection, sock)
    except:
        break
```

And here is the Java Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;    

public class Client1
{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private FileOutputStream fos = null;
    private DataInputStream din = null;
    private DataOutputStream dos = null;
    private PrintStream pout = null;

    public Client1(InetAddress address, int port) 
    {
        try {
            System.out.println("Initializing Client");
            socket = new Socket(address, port);
            din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            pout = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void send(String msg) throws IOException
    {
        pout.print(msg);
        pout.flush();
    }


    public void closeConnections() throws IOException
    {
        // Clean up when a connection is ended
        socket.close();
        din.close();
        dos.close();
        pout.close();
        scan.close();
    }


    public void sendFile(String filename)
    {
        System.out.println("Attempting to send file: "+filename);

        try{
            File file = new File(filename);
            if(!file.exists()){
                System.out.println("File does not exist. Aborting");
                return;
            }
            //send(filename);
            try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                int count;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                while( (count = fis.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    dos.write(buffer, 0 ,  count);
                }
                dos.flush();
            }

        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the while loop in the server in the `getFile()` method. Specifically, the `data = conn.recv(1024)` inside the while loop seems to loop infinitely and `data` is never null. The while loop runs just the same as if it read `while True:` but it should break once the message ends and then close the connection. As I mentioned earlier, the data arrives correctly and the client exits cleanly, it's just that the server fails to detect that there is not more data incoming.

Any suggestions on how to get this loop working properly?

Comment: Are you saying that the `conn.recv` call blocks forever or that it is returning non-empty data?

Comment: The python code works without problems for me, i.e. exiting in the place you expect once the connection is closed and waiting for a new connection. I did not test your Java code though since it is only partial code. Maybe you have forgotten to call `closeConnections` in your main code so that the server will hang and wait for more data on the same connection.

Comment: FFS, that was exactly it, I just didn't close connections so it never returned null. I spent altogether too much time on such a simple oversight. Thank you!